# How to change Google map camera from a different fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

Here's the scenario:

**1)** The starts off with `FragmentA`, which contains a Google Maps fragment, the camera is moved to the GPS location of the user

**2)** The user switches to `FragmentB`, in it there is a Place Autocomplete Fragment where i grab the location the user inputted

**3)** After clicking a button in `FragmentB`, it switches back to Fragment A and should move the camera location to the address the user inputted from `FragmentB`

**Problem:**

- i'm getting a `lateinit property mMap has not been initialized` error when trying to change `FragmentA`'s camera location from `FragmentB`. But i thought that since FragmentA was already loaded, mMap would still already be initialized. when i switch between my fragments (button nav bar) it keeps the fragment's state, so i know it's not being destroyed.

**FragmentB**

```
val button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_register) as Button
        button.setOnClickListener{
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked")
            val dialog = SuccessDialog()
            dialog.show(fragmentManager, "success dialog")

            mFragmentNavigation.clearStack()
            bottomBar.selectedItemId = R.id.nav_map
            mFragmentNavigation.switchTab(0)
            FragmentA().mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(searchedLocation, 12f))
```

**FragmentA**

```
class FragmentA: BaseFragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

.
.
.

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    checkPermission()
    try {
        val success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
            MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                activity, R.raw.style_json
            )
        )

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.")
        }
    } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e)
    }

    // location stuff
    mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
    mMap.uiSettings.isMapToolbarEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Sounds like when you are switching from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`, `Fragment A` is detaching which is causing it to recreate itself when switching back to `Fragment A`. Try saving the view that is inflated when switching between fragments so that you can restore the inflated view when necessary.

Comment: @remedy. it's not recreating because in the begining on `FragmentA` i move the map around, then go to B, and switch back to A, and the map position is still the same as i left it.

Comment: @remedy. if put `lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap` outside of the class, making it global... then it works.... but i don't think that's a good idea to have to global